# DHCP server not working properly windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, hypervisor, hyper-virtualization

Hyper-V

```
  #Setup
```

*main physical PC is using the IP address (192.168.2.2)

*Installed Windows Server 2012 R2

*DC is using (192.168.2.13 – 255.255.255.0) via external switch

*Guest PCs (Windows 7 pro x64)

*Firewall is off for Guest

*Guest has already joined the domain and current ip is dhcp using external switch (192.168.2.14 – 255.255.255.0)

*Both can ping each other and the host pc

*Installed AD DC and configured it successfully on DC

*Installed DHCP, DNS roles and configured it successfully

```
  #What I'm trying to achieve
```

AD DC with working DHCP and DNS

```
  #Problem
```

scope with 192.168.5.1-192.168.5.20 sub 255.255.255.0 not working, means client pc not receiving ip address from scope, it's getting a dhcp ip (192.168.2.14) from the external switch

DHCP log is creating error events 1035, 1036, 1045, and 10020

```
  #I already did
```

*Release and renew ip many times

*Set static ip for DC and loopback dns

*Change vSwitch for both DC & client PC  to internal & private but they're not working and getting APIPA ip addresses so i revert back to external switch

*Checked for DHCP administrators and dhcp users groups and they are already there

*Adding administrator user and normal user credentials to DHCP administrators and user groups

*Unauthorize and reauthorize scope

*Deactivate and reactivate scope

*DNS configured correctly

*Deleting the DHCP file from AD Sites and services and then reauthorize the scope

*Turn off firewall for DC

*I even installed new windows server 2016 and reconfigured everything

*Many many restarts server and DHCP service but no luck

Errors 1035, 1036 is successfully gone but 1045 is still there, also 10020 is here but i don't use ipv6 so I don't care about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a static IP on the DC that you are wishing to use as the DHCP server that is on the 192.168.5.0 subnet?  There must be an interface on the network that you wish to hand out IPs on.

The only other way around this would be to add a route on your external switch (If Layer 3 capable) and add a DHCP Helper if that is an option on your particular switch.

Comment: Do you mean that the DHCP server (which is in this case is the DC) should be in the same range of the Scope i want to create?

Comment: Should be in the same subnet but not particularly in the same range.  Above you mentioned that you are using the scope of 192.168.5.1-192.168.5.20.  You could add a static IP to the server of anything outside of that range.  For example, 192.168.5.200 would be fine.  It could be anything outside of the scope of course.  I would be leery of using anything too close to the end of the scope in case you need to expand it.

Comment: And if i want to make all clients pcs use the subnet 10.0.0.5-10.0.0.50 and only the server uses the subnet 192.168.2.13 i should consider using dhcp rely agent and dc acting as a router, am i right?

Comment: Yep, so you would need to add a scope on the DC.  Then from there you would need to make sure your external switch or whatever is performing the routing between the subnets has the "DHCP helper" or "DHCP relay" as you put it.  You would need an L3 switch for this.